# Subsetting or selecting data for a specific year [r] per week

Tags: r, plot

I want to select or subset data from a specific year. Under the code in pretty printed letters, I mention the error I get. I also have added a picture of how my dataset looks like.

What I want is to have the dates from a specific year. Then I want per week of that year with the first week starting in 01-01-2011. Eventually I want to make a line plot showing the bike rentals (cnt in the picture) for each week of the year.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5h7M.jpg)

```
Bikes_Washington$dteday <- as.Date(Bikes_Washington$dteday)
    
data_2011 <- data[Bikes_Washington$dteday > "01-01-2011" & Bikes_Washington$dteday < "31-12-2011",]
```

#object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
selectByDate(
  Bikes_Washington$dteday,
  start = "1/1/2011",
  end = "31/12/2011",
  year = 2011,
  month = 1,
  day = "weekday",
  hour = 1
```

*incorrect number of dimensions*

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

data <-
  tribble(
  ~dteday, ~cnt,
  "2011-01-01", 985,
  "2011-01-02", 131,
  "2011-01-10", 1321
)
data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   dteday       cnt
#>   <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 2011-01-01   985
#> 2 2011-01-02   131
#> 3 2011-01-10  1321

data %>%
  transmute(
    date = dteday %>% as.Date(),
    year = year(date),
    week = week(date),
    cnt
  ) %>%
  group_by(year, week) %>%
  # sum up cnt per week
  summarise(cnt = sum(cnt)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(week, cnt, color = year)) +
    geom_line()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'year'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>